# Try all combinations of spaces in a string

Tags: java, string

Id like to make a **for loop** with all possible combinations of a given string with spaces added.

Example:

```
t hefatcow
th efatcow
th efatcow
the fatcow
thef atcow
etc...
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Edit: I'm actually seeking to do this with "_" underscores, not spaces.

Comment: Try something..That's the simplest way for you..

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I haven't thats the point I'm asking how. last i checked stack overflow wasn't for code correction only. you guys have experience with many scenarios, I'm hoping this is one of them.

Comment: However, it is also not a "Do my work for me" site. You should make an attempt, and ask for help in **specific** places where you have a problem.

Comment: You call this work? its 5 lines

Comment: Considering someone else just solved your problem for free I find this comment rather offensive.

Comment: Instead of having a potential specific problem, the answer has been solved below for anyone needing to do this in the future. I see that as being far more beneficial to the site.

Comment: This isn't about whether or not i appreciate the help @reto, i thank the poster for and appreciate his answer. But did i ask for code anywhere? You guys could've just as easily posted pseudo code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could do it with something like

```
String word = "thefatcow";
for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", word.substring(0, i),
            word.substring(i));
}
```

Output is

```
t hefatcow
th efatcow
the fatcow
thef atcow
thefa tcow
thefat cow
thefatc ow
thefatco w
```

Comment: works perfectly. will mark as answer when SO lets me